# JavaScript returning the value from an inner function

Tags: javascript, web-sql

I am trying to get the value from an inner function.  Why is domain always returning undefined?  I think this is because the webSQL executes asynchronously.
I need to get the value of domain at this point in the program before I can proceed.   I think this is a closure problem but perhaps my approach is is just wrong?

```
var domain = selectDomain();

function selectDomain()
{
    var sql,
        i;

    sql = "SELECT * FROM Domain";

    database.open();
    database.query(sql, [], function(tx, result) 
    {
        for (i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++)
        {
            var domain = result.rows.item(i);   
            return domain.Domain;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right that the query executes asynchronously, and a return statement here will not work. Instead, in the callback function of the query, call another function that passes the result as a parameter, and continue your program from there.

**Edit:** I just noticed that you loop through the result, which means `domain` will be continuously overwritten by each row, and always end up with the value of the last item.

```
var domain;
selectDomain();

function selectDomain() {
  ...

  database.query(sql, [], function(tx, result) 
  {
    for (i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++)
    {
      handleResult(result.rows.item(i));
    }
  });
}

function handleResult(result) {
    domain = result.Domain;
    // Continue
}
```